# Linking one Sequelize model to two different fields from another model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, relational-database, sequelize.js

I have two models:

- `BusinessEntity`, and
- `Invoice`

I want the `Invoice` to have a `seller` and a `buyer`, both pointing to `BusinessEntity` records. So, I expect to have in the `invoices` table (the `Invoice` model) two fields: `seller_id` and `buyer_id`.

So, I did something like this:

**`BusinessEntity`**

```
const BusinessEntity = sequelize.define("business_entity", {
    display_name: Sequelize.STRING
});
```

**`Invoice`**

```
const Invoice = sequelize.define("invoice", {
    series: Sequelize.STRING,
    number: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    ...
});

// Indeed, this creates the seller_id and buyer_id fields in the invoice
Invoice.belongsTo(BusinessEntity, { as: "seller" });
Invoice.belongsTo(BusinessEntity, { as: "buyer" });
```

It doesn't seem natural to me to call `Invoice.belongsTo(BusinessEntity)`, but if I do:

```
BusinessEntity.belongsTo(Invoice, { as: "seller" });
BusinessEntity.belongsTo(Invoice, { as: "buyer" });
```

...the `seller_id` and `buyer_id` columns are not created at all. Why?

---

I inserted successfully an invoice, assiging ids from the `business_entities` table.

How am I supposed to query the `Invoice` when I want to `include` the `seller` and the `buyer` in the output?

I tried:

```
 Invoice.findOne({ include: [BusinessEntity] })
```

But that fails with this error:

```
 business_entity is not associated to invoice!
```

What's the right way to do this? How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are performing the findOne query: `Invoice.findOne({ include: [BusinessEntity] })` it is important to mention the alias, also.

So, the query you need has this format:

```
Invoice.findOne({
  include: [
    // Include the seller
    { model: BusinessEntity, as: 'seller' },
    // ...and the buyer
    { model: BusinessEntity, as: 'buyer' }
  ]
})
```